# I need to get from SQL data to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, web, software-design, web-development-server

I want little help about php, my English knowledge is not good i will explain my problem as well.

on my database have this kind of field,

```
Answers["1=>4,2=>5,3=>3,4=>1"];
```

so friends i want to get this answers to my associative array like this

```
$answers = array([1]=>4,[2]=>5,[3]=>3,[4]=>1);
```

please help me!

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a single database field. If you have a table of (num, value) and 4 rows this becomes significantly easier.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a way to resolve

```
$a = "1=>4,2=>5,3=>3,4=>1";
$a = "{" . preg_replace("/(\d+)=>/", '"${1}":', $a) . "}";
$output = json_decode($a, true);

// output
Array
(
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

- First explode them using `,` .
- Then loop through them to assign it to array after exploding by `=>`.

```
$a = '1=>4,2=>5,3=>3,4=>1';
$final = [];
foreach(explode(',', $a) as $value){
  list($key, $val) = explode('=>', $value);
  $final[$key] = $val;
  
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($final);
Output:

Array
(
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 1
)
```